# Angular URL like breadcrumbs

Tags: angular, web, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a private online shop made with Angular.

Suppose I have **products** that belong to a **group** and a **category**. A product have a unique identifier for all the shop.

In order to see a product I can just go to:

http://myshop.com/product/c30066efc5ee46278ef9bc27c99977b4

I'm thinking on adding the group and category to that URL, although I don't need them to search the product or for SEO purposes (as it is a private and non indexable site), just to act like breadcrumbs or to be more friendly for customers, like this:

http://myshop.com/men/jackets/product/c30066efc5ee46278ef9bc27c99977b4

That URL would be generated on the fly, so if I change the group name it would update it in the URL as well.

But for angular router, above URL and this one would show the same product:

http://myshop.com/asdf/asdf/product/c30066efc5ee46278ef9bc27c99977b4

Do you think this is useful? Do you find any strong disadvantage on this approach?